# Slack bot gets malformed files

Tags: python, slack-api

I've built a small slack bot which is notified when files are shared with it and downloads these files. The problem seems to be that it gets malformed files once downloaded!
I've tested on JPEG and XLSM files and can't seem to understand the issue.
When trying to download the files manually (via browser) I'm able to get the file via the 'url_private' attribute. Am I missing something? Is there a compression I have to deal with?

The code is similar to the following:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('<url_private>', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'})
if response.status_code == 200:
    use_file(response.content)
```

The weird thing is I'm able to retrieve the file (the app and bot has all the relevant scopes and permissions), so I was thinking it all should go smooth from there hence I'm stuck..

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should open the file in binary mode.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case, I'm not that interested in writing to the file as I am with getting the file in tact.